How to change the vertically arranged minipage to horizontal arrangement
The packages are copied by the whole article draft. My submitted article is the single column form. Now the icons are arranged from top to bottom, then from left to right in the order of 1,2,3,4. I want to change it to be arranged from left to right first, then from top to bottom in the order of 1,2,3,4. The purpose of doing this is: the original arrangement of four charts must be bound together (because it is a single column), I want to make the changed layout more flexible and free, for example, icons 1, 2 are bound, 3, 4 are bound, so that I can insert text or pictures above and below a row of charts, unlike the original four icons bound (less text can be inserted, pictures are almost impossible because of insufficient space) Looking forward to and thank you for your discussion! By the way, I would like to ask how to change the orange error log, because I edit the article in Overleaf so it does not affect, but it will affect the operation on Texstudio, I am not able change this kind of error even with help of chatgpt
The code is attached.
\documentclass[3p,times]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.} 
\captionsetup{labelsep=period}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{(\roman{subfigure})}
\makeatletter 

\renewcommand{\p@subfigure}{} 
\makeatother

\usepackage{pifont,color,multicol}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx,ragged2e} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{proof}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    top=1.5cm,
    bottom=1.5cm,
    left=1.5cm,
    right=1.5cm
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[hbt!] 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
\centering
\captionof{table}{Experiment 1} 
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\toprule 
$h$ & METHOD & MGTE & NFE & Time(s) \\ 
\midrule 
&XXXXXXXXX&4.084364(-16)&12000&0.519\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&1.802952(-13)&12000&0.539\\
0.025&ZZZZZZZZZ&1.562715(-5)&12000&0.587\\
&MMMMMMMM&5.960929(-13)&24000&0.719\\
&NNNNNN&1.912294(-4)&32000&0.632\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\midrule
&XXXXXXXXX&1.144546(-17)&15000&0.595\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&1.934776(-14)&15000&0.632\\
0.020&ZZZZZZZZZ&5.115801(-6)&15000&0.749\\
&MMMMMMMM&1.039706(-13)&30000&0.856\\
&NNNNNN&6.171445(-5)&40000&0.754\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\midrule
&XXXXXXXXX&1.142831(-19)&20000&0.756\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&1.089515(-15)&20000&0.932\\
0.015&ZZZZZZZZZ&1.214425(-6)&20000&0.938\\
&MMMMMMMM&1.140415(-14)&40000&1.145\\
&NNNNNN&1.450237(-5)&53333&1.014\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\midrule
&XXXXXXXXX&1.737694(-22)&30000&1.250\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&7.568127(-17)&30000&1.260\\
0.010&ZZZZZZZZZ&1.599277(-7)&30000&1.309\\
&MMMMMMMM&5.498041(-16)&60000&1.769\\
&NNNNNN&1.895651(-6)&80000&1.509\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\midrule
&XXXXXXXXX&2.648241(-27)&60000&2.447\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&1.847588(-20)&60000&2.601\\
0.005&ZZZZZZZZZ&4.996194(-9)&60000&2.688\\
&MMMMMMMM&3.887940(-18)&120000&3.390\\
&NNNNNN&5.894875(-8)&160000&3.072\\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% experiment 2
\vspace{5mm}
\centering
\captionof{table}{Experiment 2} 
\vspace{3mm}
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\toprule 
$h$ & METHOD & MGTE & NFE & Time(s) \\ 
\midrule
&XXXXXXXXX&4.256602(-21)&3000&0.092\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&1.213163(-16)&12000&0.089\\
0.1&ZZZZZZZZZ&3.294553(-7)&12000&0.161\\
&MMMMMMMM&1.998695(-14)&24000&0.146\\
&NNNNNN&9.584079(-2)&32000&0.195\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\midrule
&XXXXXXXXX&6.479610(-26)&6000&0.272\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&1.184842(-19)&15000&0.268\\
0.05&ZZZZZZZZZ&1.029791(-8)&15000&0.268\\
&MMMMMMMM&1.175856(-16)&30000&0.339\\
&NNNNNN&4.781334(-2)&40000&0.316\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\midrule
&XXXXXXXXX&9.881954(-31)&12000&0.514\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&1.156993(-22)&20000&0.560\\
0.025&ZZZZZZZZZ&3.217851(-10)&20000&0.554\\
&MMMMMMMM&1.187549(-18)&40000&0.691\\
&NNNNNN&2.389332(-2)&53333&0.764\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\midrule
&XXXXXXXXX&1.507622(-35)&24000&0.961\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&1.129826(-25)&30000&1.075\\
0.0125&ZZZZZZZZZ&1.005527(-11)&30000&1.129\\
&MMMMMMMM&1.701612(-20)&60000&1.423\\
&NNNNNN&1.194500(-2)&80000&1.324\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\midrule
&XXXXXXXXX&2.300318(-40)&48000&1.871\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&1.103319(-28)&60000&2.107\\
0.00625&ZZZZZZZZZ&3.142220(-13)&60000&2.091\\
&MMMMMMMM&2.679244(-22)&120000&2.780\\
&NNNNNN&5.972292(-3)&160000&2.606\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
% Table for Experiment 3
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
\centering
\captionof{table}{Experiment 3} 
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\toprule 
$h$ & METHOD & MGTE & NFE & Time(s) \\ 
\midrule 
&XXXXXXXXX&1.529179(-30)&12000&0.426\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&1.790330(-22)&12000&0.470\\
0.025&ZZZZZZZZZ&5.168409(-10)&12000&0.467\\
&MMMMMMMM&1.998151(-18)&24000&0.675\\
&NNNNNN&6.103274(-9)&32000&0.595\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\midrule
&XXXXXXXXX&4.303836(-32)&15000&0.517\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&1.922284(-23)&15000&0.593\\
0.020&ZZZZZZZZZ&1.693915(-10)&15000&0.594\\
&MMMMMMMM&4.654337(-19)&30000&0.794\\
&NNNNNN&1.999367(-9)&40000&0.798\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\midrule
&XXXXXXXXX&4.313117(-34)&20000&0.768\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&1.082461(-24)&20000&0.771\\
0.015&ZZZZZZZZZ&4.016910(-11)&20000&0.856\\
&MMMMMMMM&7.367519(-20)&40000&1.083\\
&NNNNNN&4.739915(-10)&53333&1.087\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\midrule
&XXXXXXXXX&6.566061(-37)&30000&1.022\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&1.877093(-26)&30000&1.079\\
0.010 &ZZZZZZZZZ&5.295473(-12)&30000&1.142\\
&MMMMMMMM&5.770130(-21)&60000&1.547\\
&NNNNNN&6.245495(-11)&80000&1.381\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\midrule
&XXXXXXXXX&1.001838(-41)&60000&2.075\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&1.833039(-29)&60000&2.340\\
0.005&ZZZZZZZZZ&1.655133(-13)&60000&2.502\\
&MMMMMMMM&8.089612(-23)&120000&3.285\\
&NNNNNN&1.951468(-12)&160000&3.022\\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% experiment 4
\vspace{5mm}
\centering
\captionof{table}{Experiment 4} 
\vspace{3mm}
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\toprule 
$h$ & METHOD & MGTE & NFE & Time(s) \\ 
\midrule
&XXXXXXXXX&7.984230(-34)&3000&1.194\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&5.731125(-19)&3000&1.126\\
0.1&ZZZZZZZZZ&7.547023(-9)&3000&1.167\\
&MMMMMMMM&9.413610(-11)&6000&1.296\\
&NNNNNN&1.435923(+1)&8000&1.202\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\midrule
&XXXXXXXXX&3.076946(-39)&6000&2.293\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&4.501143(-22)&6000&2.369\\
0.05&ZZZZZZZZZ&2.355988(-10)&6000&2.433\\
&MMMMMMMM&7.546886(-13)&12000&2.609\\
&NNNNNN&7.197297(0)&16000&2.288\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\midrule
&XXXXXXXXX&1.180164(-44)&12000&4.717\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&3.860842(-25)&12000&4.636\\
0.025&ZZZZZZZZZ&7.360857(-12)&12000&4.643\\
&MMMMMMMM&8.117874(-15)&24000&5.514\\
&NNNNNN&3.600816(0)&32000&4.811\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\midrule
&XXXXXXXXX&4.514317(-50)&24000&9.141\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&3.509066(-28)&24000&9.395\\
0.0125&ZZZZZZZZZ&2.300191(-13)&24000&8.970\\
&MMMMMMMM&1.056328(-16)&48000&10.141\\
&NNNNNN&1.800668(0)&64000&9.670\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\midrule
&XXXXXXXXX&1.724434(-55)&48000&18.993\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&3.299231(-31)&48000&18.874\\
0.00625&ZZZZZZZZZ&7.188114(-15)&48000&18.869\\
&MMMMMMMM&1.514080(-18)&96000&20.045\\
&NNNNNN&9.003635(-1)&128000&19.941\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*} 
\end{document}

The original outcome is attached.

The log is attached.


Off-topic: The geometry options top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm may be expressed more succinctily as margin=1.5cm.

Thanks for your reply about it the geometry options! I will change it.

By the way, the two "orange messages" are warning messages, not error messages.

OK, but how to correct it?

I guess it can't hurt to provide 4 instead of just 2 minipage environments.
Three additional suggestions:

Since the 4 components of the float are tables rather than figures, I'd use a table environment instead of a figure* environment. That way, you can use \caption{...} instead of \captionof{table}{...}. And, if you decide an alternative layout suits your needs better, you could place the first two minipage environments in one table and the next two minipage environments in a second table.

I would also left-align rather than center the contents of the first two columns of each table, and I would render the middle column of each table in automatic math mode.

I think you can get by with \small instead of \footnotesize to render the page of tables.



\documentclass[3p,times]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
%%\usepackage{float} % please try not to use 'H' specifier
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.} 
\captionsetup{labelsep=period,
              skip=0.333\baselineskip}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{(\roman{subfigure})}

\makeatletter 
\renewcommand{\p@subfigure}{} % are you sure you need this?
\makeatother

\usepackage{pifont,color,multicol}
%%\usepackage{multicol} % don't load packages more than once
\usepackage{%%%graphicx,% don't load packages more than once
            ragged2e} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{proof}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1.5cm}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}} % automatic math mode

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[tp] 
\small % no need for '\footnotesize'

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
\caption{Experiment 1} 
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}llCcc@{}}
\toprule 
$h$ & METHOD & \mbox{MGTE} & NFE & Time(s) \\ 
\midrule 
&XXXXXXXXX&4.084364(-16)&12000&0.519\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&1.802952(-13)&12000&0.539\\
0.025&ZZZZZZZZZ&1.562715(-5)&12000&0.587\\
&MMMMMMMM&5.960929(-13)&24000&0.719\\
&NNNNNN&1.912294(-4)&32000&0.632\\
%%
\midrule
&XXXXXXXXX&1.144546(-17)&15000&0.595\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&1.934776(-14)&15000&0.632\\
0.020&ZZZZZZZZZ&5.115801(-6)&15000&0.749\\
&MMMMMMMM&1.039706(-13)&30000&0.856\\
&NNNNNN&6.171445(-5)&40000&0.754\\
%%
\midrule
&XXXXXXXXX&1.142831(-19)&20000&0.756\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&1.089515(-15)&20000&0.932\\
0.015&ZZZZZZZZZ&1.214425(-6)&20000&0.938\\
&MMMMMMMM&1.140415(-14)&40000&1.145\\
&NNNNNN&1.450237(-5)&53333&1.014\\
%%%
\midrule
&XXXXXXXXX&1.737694(-22)&30000&1.250\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&7.568127(-17)&30000&1.260\\
0.010&ZZZZZZZZZ&1.599277(-7)&30000&1.309\\
&MMMMMMMM&5.498041(-16)&60000&1.769\\
&NNNNNN&1.895651(-6)&80000&1.509\\
%%
\midrule
&XXXXXXXXX&2.648241(-27)&60000&2.447\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&1.847588(-20)&60000&2.601\\
0.005&ZZZZZZZZZ&4.996194(-9)&60000&2.688\\
&MMMMMMMM&3.887940(-18)&120000&3.390\\
&NNNNNN&5.894875(-8)&160000&3.072\\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
\caption{Experiment 2} 
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}llCcc@{}}
\toprule 
$h$ & METHOD & \mbox{MGTE} & NFE & Time(s) \\ 
\midrule
&XXXXXXXXX&4.256602(-21)&3000&0.092\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&1.213163(-16)&12000&0.089\\
0.1&ZZZZZZZZZ&3.294553(-7)&12000&0.161\\
&MMMMMMMM&1.998695(-14)&24000&0.146\\
&NNNNNN&9.584079(-2)&32000&0.195\\
%%
\midrule
&XXXXXXXXX&6.479610(-26)&6000&0.272\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&1.184842(-19)&15000&0.268\\
0.05&ZZZZZZZZZ&1.029791(-8)&15000&0.268\\
&MMMMMMMM&1.175856(-16)&30000&0.339\\
&NNNNNN&4.781334(-2)&40000&0.316\\
%%
\midrule
&XXXXXXXXX&9.881954(-31)&12000&0.514\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&1.156993(-22)&20000&0.560\\
0.025&ZZZZZZZZZ&3.217851(-10)&20000&0.554\\
&MMMMMMMM&1.187549(-18)&40000&0.691\\
&NNNNNN&2.389332(-2)&53333&0.764\\
%%%
\midrule
&XXXXXXXXX&1.507622(-35)&24000&0.961\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&1.129826(-25)&30000&1.075\\
0.0125&ZZZZZZZZZ&1.005527(-11)&30000&1.129\\
&MMMMMMMM&1.701612(-20)&60000&1.423\\
&NNNNNN&1.194500(-2)&80000&1.324\\
%%
\midrule
&XXXXXXXXX&2.300318(-40)&48000&1.871\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&1.103319(-28)&60000&2.107\\
0.00625&ZZZZZZZZZ&3.142220(-13)&60000&2.091\\
&MMMMMMMM&2.679244(-22)&120000&2.780\\
&NNNNNN&5.972292(-3)&160000&2.606\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\bigskip
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
\caption{Experiment 3} 
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}llCcc@{}}
\toprule 
$h$ & METHOD & \mbox{MGTE} & NFE & Time(s) \\ 
\midrule 
&XXXXXXXXX&1.529179(-30)&12000&0.426\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&1.790330(-22)&12000&0.470\\
0.025&ZZZZZZZZZ&5.168409(-10)&12000&0.467\\
&MMMMMMMM&1.998151(-18)&24000&0.675\\
&NNNNNN&6.103274(-9)&32000&0.595\\
%%
\midrule
&XXXXXXXXX&4.303836(-32)&15000&0.517\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&1.922284(-23)&15000&0.593\\
0.020&ZZZZZZZZZ&1.693915(-10)&15000&0.594\\
&MMMMMMMM&4.654337(-19)&30000&0.794\\
&NNNNNN&1.999367(-9)&40000&0.798\\
%%
\midrule
&XXXXXXXXX&4.313117(-34)&20000&0.768\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&1.082461(-24)&20000&0.771\\
0.015&ZZZZZZZZZ&4.016910(-11)&20000&0.856\\
&MMMMMMMM&7.367519(-20)&40000&1.083\\
&NNNNNN&4.739915(-10)&53333&1.087\\
%%%
\midrule
&XXXXXXXXX&6.566061(-37)&30000&1.022\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&1.877093(-26)&30000&1.079\\
0.010 &ZZZZZZZZZ&5.295473(-12)&30000&1.142\\
&MMMMMMMM&5.770130(-21)&60000&1.547\\
&NNNNNN&6.245495(-11)&80000&1.381\\
%%
\midrule
&XXXXXXXXX&1.001838(-41)&60000&2.075\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&1.833039(-29)&60000&2.340\\
0.005&ZZZZZZZZZ&1.655133(-13)&60000&2.502\\
&MMMMMMMM&8.089612(-23)&120000&3.285\\
&NNNNNN&1.951468(-12)&160000&3.022\\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
\caption{Experiment 4} 
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}llCcc@{}}
\toprule 
$h$ & METHOD & \mbox{MGTE} & NFE & Time(s) \\ 
\midrule
&XXXXXXXXX&7.984230(-34)&3000&1.194\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&5.731125(-19)&3000&1.126\\
0.1&ZZZZZZZZZ&7.547023(-9)&3000&1.167\\
&MMMMMMMM&9.413610(-11)&6000&1.296\\
&NNNNNN&1.435923(+1)&8000&1.202\\
%%
\midrule
&XXXXXXXXX&3.076946(-39)&6000&2.293\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&4.501143(-22)&6000&2.369\\
0.05&ZZZZZZZZZ&2.355988(-10)&6000&2.433\\
&MMMMMMMM&7.546886(-13)&12000&2.609\\
&NNNNNN&7.197297(0)&16000&2.288\\
%%
\midrule
&XXXXXXXXX&1.180164(-44)&12000&4.717\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&3.860842(-25)&12000&4.636\\
0.025&ZZZZZZZZZ&7.360857(-12)&12000&4.643\\
&MMMMMMMM&8.117874(-15)&24000&5.514\\
&NNNNNN&3.600816(0)&32000&4.811\\
%%%
\midrule
&XXXXXXXXX&4.514317(-50)&24000&9.141\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&3.509066(-28)&24000&9.395\\
0.0125&ZZZZZZZZZ&2.300191(-13)&24000&8.970\\
&MMMMMMMM&1.056328(-16)&48000&10.141\\
&NNNNNN&1.800668(0)&64000&9.670\\
%%
\midrule
&XXXXXXXXX&1.724434(-55)&48000&18.993\\
&YYYYYYYYYY&3.299231(-31)&48000&18.874\\
0.00625&ZZZZZZZZZ&7.188114(-15)&48000&18.869\\
&MMMMMMMM&1.514080(-18)&96000&20.045\\
&NNNNNN&9.003635(-1)&128000&19.941\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\end{table*} 

\end{document}


Thanks for your detailed answer and suggestion! I try to edit the article following your code first

the new code you provided runs well in overleaf, it help  a lot, thank you for taking the time to help with it.
